# iOS - Index Out Of Range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've stumbled across an error in my application:

> fatal error: Index out of range (lldb)

I think I may have an idea as to what the problem is, however, don't have a clue on how to amend the error.

I believe due to the fact I'm using section headers, this is causing the problem. I've proof read the coding as well as trying to fix it and searching online. Below I have posted a sample of my code (didn't want to include it all as it includes a few hundred lines of code).

Essentially, I am using a TableViewController in combination with SWReveal where the user selects an option and text will appear.

```
class BackTableVC: UITableViewController {


    struct Brands {
      var sectionName : String!
        var sectionBrands : [String]!
    }


    struct ThirdView {
        var ThirdViewArray = [String]()
    }

    var brandArray = [Brands]()



    var ThirdArray = [ThirdView]()

    var brandAnswerArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        brandArray = [


            Brands(sectionName: "Bugatti", sectionBrands: ["EB 110","Veyron"])]

        ThirdArray = [ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["EB 110","Veyron"])]



 }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  brandArray[section].sectionBrands.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = brandArray[indexPath.section].sectionBrands[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CarDetailsVC

        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let ThirdAnswerArray : ThirdView

        ThirdAnswerArray = ThirdArray[indexPath.row]

        DestVC.brandAnswerArray = ThirdAnswerArray.ThirdViewArray

       DestVC.FirstString = brandAnswerArray[indexPath.row]

    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return brandArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return brandArray[section].sectionName

    }


}
    import Foundation

struct ThirdView {
    var ThirdViewArray = [String]()
}

    class CarDetailsVC: UIViewController {


       var FirstString = String()

    var brandAnswerArray = [String]()






    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        Label.text = FirstString

    }

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            _ = segue.destinationViewController as! CarDetailsVC            
        }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

My ThirdView struct and CarDetailsVC are in separate .swift files.

The line which is giving me grief is:

```
       DestVC.FirstString = brandAnswerArray[indexPath.row]
```

P.S. if I was to do this:

```
DestVC.FirstString = "Hello World"
```

Hello World is shown when selecting only the first option, then the code/application breaks an I get the same error "index out of range" on the line:

```
        ThirdAnswerArray = ThirdArray[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple answer is that your brandAnswerArray doesn't have enough values to give you the thing at index indexPath.row.  i.e. If you have an array with 5 values and you ask it for array[8], the app will crash because index 8 doesn't exist.

Specifically, you are telling your table that you have a certain number of cells/rows:

brandArray[section].sectionBrands.count

That means for every integer, from 0, to whatever brandArray[section].sectionBrands.count is, the table is going to ask you to generate a cell.  Therefore, that is the range that your indexPath.row can have.

BUT: In your prepareForSegue, you are accessing brandAnswerArray[indexPath.row], and brandAnswerArray simply doesn't have enough values to give you whatever is at that requested index (which is a risk, since you used a different portion of data to build the table).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however, my ThirdArray consists of two values and there are two cells. Shouldn't that be suffice enough? Well, I know the answer due to the application keep on crashing. How would I assign values to brandAnswerArray? What would be the best way?